Calculate number of customers with 2+ orders within date range
I want to calculate the count of active customers everyday from a sales table containing data from 2021. The table has columns order id, order date, email, and gross amount.
Active Customer – If I am looking for 01-05-2024, active customers would be the number of people who have placed 2 or more orders between ‘01-05-2024 – 400days’ and 01-05-2024’ that is within 400 days from that day. Same for 02-05-2024 and so on.
Is it possible to do this in SQL or Tableau?
I am not able to get the data for everyday.

Of course it's possible! What have you tried so far?

However, the approach should be as follow:

Calculate the first order for each customer in your date range
Now left join the same table to this CTE in order to get the next order_cnt per customer


PS: You can use more CTEs to reduce the processing costs.

with first_order as (

select 
customer_id,  
order_id,
order_creation_timestamp

from orders_table

where date_dimenstion between '2024-5-1' and ('2024-5-1' + 400)

qualify row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by order_creation_timestamp desc) = 1 -- To make sure you're getting the first order of the customer. 

)

select
 fo.customer_id,
 count(distinct ot.order_id) order_cnt

from first_order fo

left join orders_table ot
on fo.customer_id = ot.customer_id -- You want to see the next orders of the same customer. 
and fo.order_creation_timestamp < ot.order_creation_timestamp -- You need to make sure that the next orders are after the first order. If you want to count the first order use "<=" instead
and timestamp_diff(ot.order_creation_timestamp, fo.order_creation_timestamp, day) <= 400 -- You need to make sure that the next orders are happening only 400 days after the first order
and ot.date_dimenstion between '2024-5-1' and ('2024-5-1' + 400) -- You need to make sure you don't bring redundant data.

group by customer_id
having order_cnt > 1 -- To make sure you just see the customers with more than 1 order. 


order by order_cnt desc

